# How many numbers below $1000$ AND ABOVE ZERO are there with no odd digits in them? WITH NO DIGIT REPEATED e.g. $246$, $208$

Tags: combinatorics

**My solution.**

$73$ numbers below $1000$ have no odd digits. Here's the corrected breakdown:

One-digit numbers: there are $5$ choices for the one-digit number $(0, 2, 4, 6, 8)$.

Two-digit numbers: Now, with a valid tens digit $(2, 4, 6, 8)$, there are $5$ choices for the unit digit $(0, 2, 4, 6, 8)$, making a total of $4 \cdot 5 = 20$ even two-digit numbers.

Three-digit numbers: Similar to before, there are $4$ choices for the hundreds digit $(2, 4, 6, 8)$. Then $4$ choices for the tens digit (including $0$), and $3$ choices for the units digit, leading to $4 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = 48$ even three-digit numbers.

Adding these contributions: $48 + 20 + 5 = 73$.

​Am I correct to think this?

Comment: Are you also assuming that digits don't repeat? Your analysis makes it seem that way.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Are you allowing repetitions or not? You seem to block them for three digit numbers but I guess you allow them for two digit numbers?

Comment: If you allow repetitions, then there are $125$ in total as each digit can be any of the $5$ even ones (allowing a lead $0$ just means you have fewer digits.  Thus $22=022$).

Comment: how many "numbers"? By "numbers" do you mean "integers"? "positive integers"? "non-negative integers"? All have different answers. In mathematics details matter.

Comment: You are making it way too hard.  Each position can be one of any $5$ digits and digits are allowed to repeat.  Once you realize a leading zero is equivalently the same as simple being a less then three digit number you don't have to worry about the leading terms.  The only real issue is whether you are doing positive integers (where $0$ doesn't count) or all integers (in which there are an infinite number) or decimal representation of reals (ditto).

Comment: YES NO DIGIT REPEATED SORRY FOR NOT MENTIONING IT

Comment: May this is the first time you use internet, so I will let you know that writing in ALLCAPS is the equivalent to yelling. Please, don't yell in this forum.

Answer (score 2):

In response to the comment below, I must clarify this solution assumes we are talking of only whole numbers (0 and positive integers).

Your answer appears to be wrong. The wording of the question suggests we are to consider all numbers below $1000$ that don't contain odd digits. Meaning $444$ is valid. That means repetition is allowed.

Also, you don't have to consider the cases separately.

For numbers with up to $3$ digits, consider three positions which can be populated with any of the $5$ even digits.

So. $5 \times 5 \times 5 = 125$.

To make things clearer, here are a couple of examples.

$002$ represents $2$ and $015$ represents $15$.

Comment: Is $0$ a valid number? Is $-26480286$?  What about $248.846284$?

Comment: @fleablood yeah, i didn't think about all the non-integers or even negative integers. But honestly, i would say $0$ is the real bone of contention. The other assumptions are common sense assumptions. The question should have been worded better.

Answer (score -1):

Alternative approach:

Since $~0~$ is not an odd digit, you can **harmlessly** zero fill (on the left) numbers less than $~100~$ without affecting the tally of how many numbers have no odd digits.

Then, assuming that you are examining the numbers from 000 through 999 inclusive, you can interpret the problem as a probability problem, since each of the 3 digits (1's place, 10's place, 100's place) varies randomly with the elements in $~\{0,1,2,\cdots,9\}.~$

The probability of any random number having all even digits is therefore $~\dfrac{1}{2^3}.~$  Since there are $~1000~$ such numbers, the talley must be $~1000 \times \dfrac{1}{2^3} = 125.~$

If you exclude $~0,~$ and decide that you are only interested in the numbers from 1 through 999, inclusive, then the tally will be $~125 - 1 = 124.$